# Use a temp table's result in a view

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, stored-procedures, view, temporary-tables

I am using a temp table in a stored procedure.

I need to use that temp table's result in my view.

How can I do that?

Comment: Please include as much information as possible in the question itself! There are a few articles on how to ask questions here on my profile - you might like to take a look?

Answer (score 1):

> I need to use that temp table's result in my view.

Why?

Creating views on temporary tables is not allowed.

```
create table #foo(id int)
go
create view vfoo 
as
select * from #foo
```

fails with

```
Msg 4508, Level 16, State 1, Procedure vfoo, Line 4 [Batch Start Line 9]
Views or functions are not allowed on temporary tables. Table names that begin with '#' denote temporary tables.
```

Comment: HI David, Basically I am using one temp table in my stored proc. I am populating some data on it. I need that temp table result in my view. If any other way also you can suggest. Kindly help

Comment: Hope you got my use case

Comment: Why can't you load the data into a regular table?

Comment: Yea that we can do. Is there any other way?

Comment: If any other way means it would be better. Because it has some huge data. I cant create one more regular table

Comment: How about a Table-Valued Function instead of a Stored Procedure?

Comment: No we cant change. Is there any other way?